# XML to JSON Conversion based on XML Schema

Tags: xml, json, web-services, xsd

is there a way to convert XML to JSON and Viceversa based on XML  Schema ...

Then route the XML or JSON to another WEB Service  .

Which Technology should is use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xml binding for `xml<->Object` mapping available in javax package.
Also there is a good json parser `Object<->json` [http://jackson.codehaus.org/](http://jackson%20json%20parser)

There are good examples provided online for web services 
[http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program](http://example%201)

[http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/](http://example%202)